# Strange authentication requirement in CUPS web interface

Tags: cups

I'm accessing a print server's CUPS web interface - using an SSH tunnel so that access is on the local host. CUPS is configured fine (I think) and I can print.

However, when I try to do something like, say, Add a New Printer, I get an "Authentication" username+password prompt from my browser, with the message being "CUPS". What am I supposed to enter in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `root` user's credentials.  In my experience, that is the credentials it is looking for.

Comment: While it seems to me like a very bad idea to take the root user's credentials over a web connection - it seems that's what CUPS does expect. Strange.